# Using react-router w/ brunch/babel

Tags: babeljs, react-router, brunch

I'm attempting use `react-router` in my brunch/babel setup. In my app.js I have:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router"
```

This however gives me:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "history/lib/createHashHistory" from "react-router/Router"

When looking at the referenced line I see:

```
var _historyLibCreateHashHistory = require('history/lib/createHashHistory');
```

When inspecting the `app.js` that's generated via brunch I see:

```
require.register('history/createBrowserHistory', function(exports,req,module) {
  ...
});
```

How do I go about fixing this so that `createBrowserHistory` gets imported properly?

Comment: this issue was fixed by upgrading brunch to 2.2.3. seems like it had a bug that prevented loading some modules

Comment: Hey Kyle, did you figure it out by any chance?

Comment: @Andrea.cabral Unfortunately I did not but I didn't give the issue too much attention. I ended up using Webpack for my Elixir Phoenix application and it's been working perfectly. Hopefully at some point I can revisit it though.

Comment: Awesome, I guess I will do the same ;) thanks for answering back!

Answer (score 1):

The module `history` is listed as a peer dependency by `react-router`, which means that you need to install it yourself through the command `npm install history --save`.